# How do I wait for the next event in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I'm writing a very simple UDP client example. Here is the code:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var msg = new Buffer('hello');
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.send(msg, 0, msg.length, 6000, '127.0.0.1', function(err, bytes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('UDP message sent');
});
s.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
});
```

How do I make my program wait for the next event, i.e. a reply from the server? I've tried using setImmediate, but it gets my cpu up to 100%, so it seems to be a busy wait. Here is the code again:

```
function wait() {
    setImmediate(wait);
}    
wait();
```

Comment: Node is an event driven system.  You listen for events.  You never make your code wait.

Comment: That's my question: how do I listen for events without my execution reaching the end of my code and just exiting?

Comment: Oh... just noticed that it doesn't exit, in fact. Guess that I have to read more about Node.js internals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dgram's `message` event. `message` has a callback with the parameters `msg` and `rinfo`. `msg` contains the buffer of the actual packet you received and `rinfo` contains information about the sender (such as IP address and port).

Example:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var msg = new Buffer('hello');
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.send(msg, 0, msg.length, 6000, '127.0.0.1', function(err, bytes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('UDP message sent');
});

s.on('message', function (msg, rinfo) {
    console.log('Message from '+packetInfo.address+': '+msg.toString("utf8"));
});
```

Comment: This was a typo: my handler was supposed to be there in the question, but if I don't make execution stop, my program will just exit. That's the point of my question. Thanks for helping so far :)